# Nginx + PHP-FPM + Multiple Server Blocks

Tags: nginx, php

All,

I am attempting to configure nginx to serve up 3 separate directories and force the document root ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) to be that directory.

Example: Give this url, `http://127.0.0.1/helpdesk` , we would like our $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to be /var/www/helpdesk

Any ideas? Our block for /helpdesk looks like:

```
  location /helpdesk {      
     fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/helpdesk;
     root /var/www/helpdesk
  }
```

Comment: I would recommend using one root directive then let each directory be in that root directory.

Comment: Your subject mentions multiple server blocks. Are they different subdomains on the same host?